# How Can I plot 3D figures using discrete data in one dimension?

Tags: plotting

I have an approximate solution for the function `u[x,t]` using the semi-discretization method in time step. For example, I have `u[x,ti]` for all `x` and some `ti`. I want to plot a 3D figure for this function and I don't know how to plot it.

Comment: What does your "approximate solution" look like?

Comment: Hi Parnia, welcome to Mathematica.SE! `Plot3D`, `ListPlot3D`, and `DiscretePlot3D` come to mind. Did you perhaps try those?

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly instead of a function defined analytically:

```
f[x_, t_] := Sin[x^2 + t^2]
```

You have a set of curves resulting from a discrete variable, similarly to:

```
fset[x_] = f[x, #] & /@ (Range[100]/50)
```

[image]

I think the easiest way to plot this is to make 2nd variable discrete too and use `ListPlot3D`:

```
ListPlot3D[fset /@ (Range[100]/50),  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Another way, "preserving" continuous definition of one variable and keeping the other discrete is to use `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[ Evaluate@Transpose[{ConstantArray[x, 100], Range[100]/50, 
    fset[x]}], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[.5]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]